# Authentication with google

Tags: android, google-authentication

Based on [this](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html) I'm trying to auth with google. But a GoogleAuthException is thrown and the message is "BadUsername". This confuses me since I'm picking the email/username by the account picker. Anyone got a clue about what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT = 1000;
    String mEmail; // Received from newChooseAccountIntent(); passed to getToken()
    private static final String SCOPE =
            "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        pickUserAccount();
    }

    private void pickUserAccount() {
        String[] accountTypes = new String[]{"com.google"};
        Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                accountTypes, false, null, null, null, null);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT) {
            // Receiving a result from the AccountPicker
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mEmail = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                // With the account name acquired, go get the auth token
                Toast.makeText(this, mEmail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ConfirmEmailTask confirmEmailTask = new ConfirmEmailTask(this, SCOPE, mEmail);
                confirmEmailTask.execute();

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The account picker dialog closed without selecting an account.
                // Notify users that they must pick an account to proceed.
//              Toast.makeText(this, R.string.pick_account, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        // Later, more code will go here to handle the result from some exceptions...
    }

    public class ConfirmEmailTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        Activity mActivity;
        String mScope;
        String mEmail;

        ConfirmEmailTask(Activity activity, String name, String scope) {
            this.mActivity = activity;
            this.mScope = scope;
            this.mEmail = name;
        }

        /**
         * Executes the asynchronous job. This runs when you call execute()
         * on the AsyncTask instance.
         */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                String token = fetchToken();
                if (token != null) {
                    return token;
                    // Insert the good stuff here.
                    // Use the token to access the user's Google data.
//                  Toast.makeText(mActivity, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // The fetchToken() method handles Google-specific exceptions,
                // so this indicates something went wrong at a higher level.
                // TIP: Check for network connectivity before starting the AsyncTask.
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Gets an authentication token from Google and handles any
         * GoogleAuthException that may occur.
         */
        protected String fetchToken() throws IOException {
            try {
                return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
                Log.d(TAG, "error");
                // GooglePlayServices.apk is either old, disabled, or not present
                // so we need to show the user some UI in the activity to recover.
//              mActivity.handleException(userRecoverableException);
            } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
                // Some other type of unrecoverable exception has occurred.
                // Report and log the error as appropriate for your app.
                Log.d(TAG, fatalException.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the stacktrace.

```
W/System.err﹕ com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: BadUsername
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at dk.eterno.bloatwareremover.MainActivity$ConfirmEmailTask.fetchToken(MainActivity.java:138)
W/System.err﹕ at dk.eterno.bloatwareremover.MainActivity$ConfirmEmailTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:115)
W/System.err﹕ at dk.eterno.bloatwareremover.MainActivity$ConfirmEmailTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:97)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Post log, the only strange thing I see is getUsername() doesn't actually go anywhere. So the account picker works, you get the data, throw a valid email to google and you get this error?

Comment: I removed getUsername(). I simply want to toast the token for now. I've added the stacktrace to my question. Seems like quite a few people had the same error. Mostly because they forgot to prefix the scope with oauth2:

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record.

The problem here is that you are passing wrong the arguments in this:

```
ConfirmEmailTask confirmEmailTask = new ConfirmEmailTask(this, SCOPE, mEmail);
```

The class constructor is defined like

```
ConfirmEmailTask(Activity activity, String name, String scope) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mScope = scope;
        this.mEmail = name;
}
```

So change the order of parameters in one of them.